# Powershell : When the arraylist has windows path, how to remove the array value?

Tags: arraylist, powershell-4.0

```
PS > $folderName = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName

PS > $array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$folderName

PS > $array

FullName
--------
D:\aa
D:\bb
D:\cc
D:\dd

PS > $array.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

If want remove array data `D:\bb`, `$array.Remove("D:\bb")` not work,

array data has not changed, but `$array.RemoveAt(1)` is work, please give advice.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

today find answer, is work :

```
$array.RemoveAt($array.FullName.IndexOf("D:\bb"))
```